# Using current year PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i want to see all policy which is realese in current year. 
It means if user input 2017 it need to search for policy which is release in 2017 ('1-jan-2017' to '31-dec-2017') 
If user input 2016 it need to search for policy which is release in 2016  ('1-jan-2016' to '31-dec-2016')
and soo on. 
As you can see from picture all those data need to be store in excel file which need to contain 11 row and 2 column(tarifa,count)

```
    select substr(tarifa,1,2),count(*)
from   pol p, uvod u, doppov d
where  (datum_dop >=sysdate)  AND (datum_dop<=sysdate)
and izdavanje>=sysdate
and p.orgjed = u.sorgz (+)
--and DATUM_PREKIDA is not null
and p.polica=d.polica and d.pov_dopl='P'
and d.status='F'
and cisti_ao(p.polica)!=0 
group by substr(tarifa,1,2)
```

[image]

When I run this query I get error  `no rows selected`
But after I modify this query and put year I get only 10 column with 2 row

```
select substr(tarifa,1,2),count(*)
from   pol p, uvod u, doppov d
where  (datum_dop >='1-jan-12')  AND (datum_dop<='31-dec-13')
and izdavanje>='01-jul-07'
and p.orgjed = u.sorgz (+)
--and DATUM_PREKIDA is not null
and p.polica=d.polica and d.pov_dopl='P'
and d.status='F'
and cisti_ao(p.polica)!=0 
group by substr(tarifa,1,2)


SU   COUNT(*)
-- ----------
01        188
02         29
04          1
05          1
06          4
07          3
08          1
10          2
```

But I need to get 11 column with 2 row. 
I have no idea where I made mistake and what I did wrong.
Can anyone help me, pleasee ! ! ! I would be very thankfull
Cheers ! ! !

**Source code Procedure**

```
PROCEDURE OTKAZANE IS

application OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
workbooks OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
workbook OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
worksheets OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
worksheet OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
cell OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
range OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
range_col OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;

args OLE2.LIST_TYPE;
VRIJEDNOST VARCHAR2(500);

form_name VARCHAR2(100);
f_block VARCHAR2(100);
l_block VARCHAR2(100);
f_item VARCHAR2(100);
l_item VARCHAR2(100);
cur_item VARCHAR2(100);

item_name VARCHAR2(100);
baslik VARCHAR2(100);
row_n NUMBER;
col_n NUMBER;
filename VARCHAR2(100);
BROJAC NUMBER:=0;

/*Otkazane police u bilo kojem periodu */

cursor o1 is 

select substr(tarifa,1,2),count(*)
from   pol p, uvod u, doppov d
where  (datum_dop >='1-jan-12')  AND (datum_dop<='31-dec-13')
and izdavanje>='01-jul-07'
and p.orgjed = u.sorgz (+)
--and DATUM_PREKIDA is not null
and p.polica=d.polica and d.pov_dopl='P'
and d.status='F'
and cisti_ao(p.polica)!=0 
group by substr(tarifa,1,2)



BEGIN       
message('huhu');

END;
```

**UPDATE**

```
COUNT(DISTINCTSUBSTR(TARIFA,1,2))
---------------------------------
                                1
                                1
                                1
                                1
                                1
```

Comment: There must be 10 distinct value for `substr(tarifa,1,2)` so you are getting 10 rows only.  Can you please remove group by clause and change select clause from `select substr(tarifa,1,2),count(*)` to `select count ( distinct substr(tarifa,1,2)) ` and share the output?

Comment: I update question. YOu can see in question uotput log

Comment: I think you forgot to remove the GROUP BY. It must be giving one-row answer.

Comment: I get 

COUNT(DISTINCTSUBSTR(TARIFA,1,2))
---------------------------------
                                0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is datum_dop, is it a DATE column? Because you are comparing it to a string containing the date. You would probably best be suited by just comparing the year. Reword the where clause to:

```
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM datum_dop) = my_year_input
```

Or, if you have two inputs for start date and end date.

```
WHERE datum_dop BETWEEN my_start_date AND my_end_date
```

But always make sure these are actually dates, if they arent, do a TO_DATE with the appropriate format.

Comment: datum_dop is DATE column